# Rails app to engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

How we can convert a existing rails app(3.2.11) into a engine. We have some  defined functionality in our rails app and we want to use this rails app functionality as engine so that we can add/share/mount this functionality with other rails app.

Do we have any available gem or any idea for this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have recently started doing this at my company and we will never look back.  Engine gems are great for using the same logic across multiple projects.

That said, start with this railscast: [Mountable Engines](http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines) (I think this is the right link, it is blocked here at work so I can't verify for sure. If it's not then just google "railscasts engines.")

Also, check out the documentation [here.](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html)

This is where we started and we released our engine in no time.